# HomePod as a voice-activated dialing device

Tags: call, homepod

I would like to plant two listening devices (HomePods) in the house for dad, such that he can verbally call mom's iPhone or sister's iPhone.   We are retiring dad's iPhone and the cellular service as he no longer uses it.  Assume dad has lost use of his hands

Given the retirement of dad's iPhone, can the HomePod be configured to achieve said objective to verbally connect to mom's or sister's iPhone?  Would this be confined to FaceTime audio?

Can an iPod or iPad be substituted for an iPhone if using FaceTime Audio in this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

The HomePod can make phone calls using an iPhone or iPad to handle the request. This could be FaceTime Audio, if you have no cell plan.

It's possible that you would be required to say "FaceTime Audio" when prompting it, but you can certainly make a FaceTime Audio call.

You cannot make a call without a device on the same Wi-Fi network that handles the call.

https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/use-for-phone-calls-apdeaa15a6c3/homepod

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you keep an iPhone or Apple Watch with cellular and cellular service that allows wifi calling.

Even though Mac and iPad and iPod can call when the iPhone is away from the same network, HomePod needs to connect directly to an iPhone to make cell calls.

Depending on the hands and arms of your family member a watch may not be suitable, but I have great luck with hey Siri and my Apple Watch with limited touch for some call and messaging function. The benefit here is someone else with an iPhone can now set up an Apple Watch for someone that doesn’t sign in to their own iPhone.

The phone with WiFi calling is the most full featured calling solution, hence the recommendation to keep that running. It also ensures your family can place and receive calls from anyone using non-Apple devices such as android smart phones, other cell phones or land lines.

You’ll need to enable personal requests and manage the AppleID for either scenario. I prefer FaceTime audio due to the clarity of the calls, so when it works I always use it, but it just doesn’t work enough to recommend it as the only calling option for HomePod.

Comment: Are you sure the HomePod can dial over Wi-Fi calling without a device locally? Personal requests require the device to be on the Wi-Fi network anyways.

Comment: I have made calls without my phone at work using HomePod in the past (drive to work, realize you left the phone at home, etc…). I can retest later today at home as well.

Comment: Good to know - if you could make sure any other devices that can make calls (watch, ipad, etc) aren't on either

Comment: The HomePod needs the iPhone local now - I have tested with and without Private Relay and only Mac and iPad can call when the iPhone isn’t on the “local” network. Thanks @Ezekiel - you nailed it and I’ll edit my answer so that part isn’t wrong